# nginx Fast CGI Cache Redis Cache for WordPress

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fastcgi, redis

I have a site running around 60 plugins and around 5000 users.
I used to be quite slow so I set up nginx with fast cgi caching which workes like a charm. However it (of course) is set up to skip the cache when a user is logged in into the backend (e.g. /wp-admin in our case).

I experienced when using Redis cache it also speeds up the backend for logged in users. I know this is due to the whole concept of redis cache (I understand redis cache works as object cache that caches the database requests) so I wondered: Is it possible to use nginx caching (for not logged in users) in combination with redis caching (e.g. if nginx is not serving cached files)?

I assume nginx would serve cached files if there are any and if the nginx configuration allows it. If not, nginx would not serve cached files and files could be served using Redis.

If anybody has experience in that, I appreciate any answer.

Comment: 60 plugins is insane, that's part of your problem. To use Redis you probably have another plugin installed and configured, and it's called by PHP, right? Please edit your question to specify approximately what percentage of your users log in and exactly how Redis is used. I would configure Nginx as a page cache for users not logged in, then if you have Redis working as a plugin it will only work for logged in users. We need more information on your setup to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, 60 plugins is way to much. I tend not install not many plugins, but the template needs many custom made plugins which I cannot delete right now.  For nginx purge caching I have the nginx helper plugin installed, for Redis I use a custom PHP script by eric mann: https://github.com/ericmann/Redis-Object-Cache (actually I set up Redis b this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-redis-caching-to-speed-up-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04). I didn't combine those two yet (Redis and Nginx Fast-CGI) though.

Comment: Mike, if you want help you need to edit your question to provide all the information I asked for.